# How to install dotnet tool with nuke

Tags: nuke-build

I am new to Nuke, trying to transition from Cake to Nuke.
In Cake I have the option to install (locally) tools with:

```
#module nuget:?package=Cake.DotNetTool.Module&version=0.3.0
```

and

```
#tool dotnet:?package=my.package.id&version=1.0.1
```

I have tried this in Nuke:

```
[PackageExecutable(
    packageId: "my.package.id",
    packageExecutable: "mypakagedtool.exe",
    Version = "1.0.1")]
readonly Tool MyPackagedTool;
```

but that returns a:

```
Assertion failed: Could not find package 'my.package.id' (1.0.1) using:
 - Project assets file 
 - NuGet packages config
```

I guess this is not for dotnet tools, but for nuget tools?

Comment: http://www.nuke.build/docs/authoring-builds/cli-tools.html first note. dotnet tools are no exception.

Comment: @Matthias thanks for your feedback, and sorry for being a noob, but does this get the tool installed in my build directory? I would really appreciate a working sample. :-)

Comment: Including the <PackageDownload> to the project file DOES get the package downloaded to ~\.nuget\packages\packageId\version\tools\netcoreapp2.1\any, but as dll's I have no Idea how to invoke the tool.

With dotnet tool install (--global) I get a .exe that I can invoke as a Tool from Nuke. But I DO prefer a (local) install of a specific version.

Comment: There is no need to install a global tool when it is used from a build. The dll can be invoked just as any other executable.

Comment: It is only easy, when you know how. Maybe I am an idiot, but I don't

Comment: I just explained something?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I made it work, was to include this in the build.csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageDownload Include="MyPackageId" Version="[1.0.1]" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and in Build.cs:

```
[PackageExecutable("MyPackageId", "MyTool.dll")] readonly Tool MyTool;
```

then the tool can be invoked with:

```
MyTool("arguments");
```

...and of course nuget.config should be setup to give access to the package repository.

Comment: I guess the solution I tried in the question was close to the solution, had I only realized that there is no .exe (which is a product of dotnet tool install), but the Personal Access Token used in my nuget.config was expired, which derailed me completely.

Answer (score 3):

Within `Nuke Build` you can do the following (this example is for [OctopusTools](https://nuke.build/api/Nuke.Common/Nuke.Common.Tools.Octopus.html)):

`nuke :addpackage OctopusTools`

This results in the this `<ItemGroup/>` element being added to the `.csproj` of the Build (Nuke) project:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageDownload Include="OctopusTools" Version="[9.0.0]" />
</ItemGroup>
```